# External monitor attached to laptop keeps flickering black for a few seconds, periodically

Tags: display, monitor, xrandr

I have a Dell laptop (Intel HD 5500 graphics) with 4K screen (3200x1800) attached to a 4K monitor (3840x2160).
Periodically (every 2-8 minutes) the external monitor screen will go black for a few seconds, and then turn back on (this does not do it when booted into windows with same monitor & laptop).

`xrandr` output shown below. Initially I thought because the laptop & monitor had different refresh rates, that might be causing it (60.00 vs 59.98).
However, when I created and tried applying a new mode to the monitor

```
$ xrandr --output DP-1 --mode 3840x2160_60.00
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

Please help me figure out why my external monitor screen is flickering off. Let me know what other information you need.

Output of `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 3960, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected 3200x1800+348+2160 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 294mm x 165mm
   3200x1800     59.98*+
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   1920x1200     59.95  
   1920x1080     59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
DP-1 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  29.98  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   2048x1280     59.99  
   1920x1200     59.88  
   1920x1080     60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94    24.00    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
   3840x2160_60.00  59.98
```

Output of `xrandr --verbose`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 3960, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected 3200x1800+348+2160 (0x46) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 294mm x 165mm
    Identifier: 0x42
    Timestamp:  4046994
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       1
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff004d10211400000000
        32180104a51d11780ede50a3544c9926
        0f505400000001010101010101010101
        010101010101cd9180a0c00834703020
        350026a5100000180000001000000000
        00000000000000000000000000fe0030
        35503748854c513133335a3100000000
        0002410328001200000b010a2020001b
    scaling mode: Full aspect 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
  3200x1800 (0x46) 373.250MHz -HSync -VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  3200 start 3248 end 3280 total 3360 skew    0 clock 111.09KHz
        v: height 1800 start 1803 end 1808 total 1852           clock  59.98Hz
  2048x1536 (0x47) 266.950MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  2048 start 2200 end 2424 total 2800 skew    0 clock  95.34KHz
        v: height 1536 start 1537 end 1540 total 1589           clock  60.00Hz
  1920x1440 (0x48) 234.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2256 total 2600 skew    0 clock  90.00KHz
        v: height 1440 start 1441 end 1444 total 1500           clock  60.00Hz
  1856x1392 (0x49) 218.300MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1856 start 1952 end 2176 total 2528 skew    0 clock  86.35KHz
        v: height 1392 start 1393 end 1396 total 1439           clock  60.01Hz
  1792x1344 (0x4a) 204.800MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1792 start 1920 end 2120 total 2448 skew    0 clock  83.66KHz
        v: height 1344 start 1345 end 1348 total 1394           clock  60.01Hz
  1920x1200 (0x4b) 154.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  74.04KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1203 end 1209 total 1235           clock  59.95Hz
  1920x1080 (0x4c) 138.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  59.93Hz
  1600x1200 (0x4d) 162.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1664 end 1856 total 2160 skew    0 clock  75.00KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1201 end 1204 total 1250           clock  60.00Hz
  1680x1050 (0x4e) 146.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock  59.95Hz
  1680x1050 (0x4f) 119.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1728 end 1760 total 1840 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1080           clock  59.88Hz
  1600x1024 (0x50) 103.125MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1600 end 1656 total 1664 skew    0 clock  61.97KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1024 end 1029 total 1030           clock  60.17Hz
  1400x1050 (0x51) 122.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1488 end 1640 total 1880 skew    0 clock  64.89KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1052 end 1064 total 1082           clock  59.98Hz
  1280x1024 (0x52) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1440x900 (0x53) 106.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1520 end 1672 total 1904 skew    0 clock  55.93KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  934           clock  59.89Hz
  1280x960 (0x54) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1488 total 1800 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
        v: height  960 start  961 end  964 total 1000           clock  60.00Hz
  1360x768 (0x55) 84.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1360 start 1432 end 1568 total 1776 skew    0 clock  47.72KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock  59.80Hz
  1360x768 (0x56) 72.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1360 start 1408 end 1440 total 1520 skew    0 clock  47.37KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  790           clock  59.96Hz
  1152x864 (0x57) 81.620MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1336 total 1520 skew    0 clock  53.70KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  895           clock  60.00Hz
  1024x768 (0x58) 133.475MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1024 start 1100 end 1212 total 1400 skew    0 clock  95.34KHz
        v: height  768 start  768 end  770 total  794           clock  60.04Hz
  1024x768 (0x59) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  960x720 (0x5a) 117.000MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start 1024 end 1128 total 1300 skew    0 clock  90.00KHz
        v: height  720 start  720 end  722 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
  928x696 (0x5b) 109.150MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   928 start  976 end 1088 total 1264 skew    0 clock  86.35KHz
        v: height  696 start  696 end  698 total  719           clock  60.05Hz
  896x672 (0x5c) 102.400MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   896 start  960 end 1060 total 1224 skew    0 clock  83.66KHz
        v: height  672 start  672 end  674 total  697           clock  60.01Hz
  960x600 (0x5d) 77.000MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start  984 end 1000 total 1040 skew    0 clock  74.04KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  617           clock  60.00Hz
  960x540 (0x5e) 69.250MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start  984 end 1000 total 1040 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
        v: height  540 start  541 end  544 total  555           clock  59.99Hz
  800x600 (0x5f) 81.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  832 end  928 total 1080 skew    0 clock  75.00KHz
        v: height  600 start  600 end  602 total  625           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x60) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  800x600 (0x61) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
  840x525 (0x62) 73.125MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   840 start  892 end  980 total 1120 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  529 total  544           clock  60.01Hz
  840x525 (0x63) 59.500MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   840 start  864 end  880 total  920 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  529 total  540           clock  59.88Hz
  800x512 (0x64) 51.562MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  800 end  828 total  832 skew    0 clock  61.97KHz
        v: height  512 start  512 end  514 total  515           clock  60.17Hz
  700x525 (0x65) 61.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   700 start  744 end  820 total  940 skew    0 clock  64.89KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  532 total  541           clock  59.98Hz
  640x512 (0x66) 54.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  664 end  720 total  844 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height  512 start  512 end  514 total  533           clock  60.02Hz
  720x450 (0x67) 53.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   720 start  760 end  836 total  952 skew    0 clock  55.93KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  454 total  467           clock  59.89Hz
  640x480 (0x68) 54.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  688 end  744 total  900 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
        v: height  480 start  480 end  482 total  500           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0x69) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  680x384 (0x6a) 42.375MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   680 start  716 end  784 total  888 skew    0 clock  47.72KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  390 total  399           clock  59.80Hz
  680x384 (0x6b) 36.000MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   680 start  704 end  720 total  760 skew    0 clock  47.37KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  390 total  395           clock  59.96Hz
  576x432 (0x6c) 40.810MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   576 start  608 end  668 total  760 skew    0 clock  53.70KHz
        v: height  432 start  432 end  434 total  447           clock  60.06Hz
  512x384 (0x6d) 32.500MHz -HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   512 start  524 end  592 total  672 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  388 total  403           clock  60.00Hz
  400x300 (0x6e) 20.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   400 start  420 end  484 total  528 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  300 start  300 end  302 total  314           clock  60.32Hz
  400x300 (0x6f) 18.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   400 start  412 end  448 total  512 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  300 start  300 end  301 total  312           clock  56.34Hz
  320x240 (0x70) 12.587MHz -HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   320 start  328 end  376 total  400 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  240 start  245 end  246 total  262           clock  60.05Hz
DP-1 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (0x71) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
    Identifier: 0x43
    Timestamp:  4046994
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:     HDMI-1
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0010acbea042354c30
        131a0104a5351e783ae245a8554da326
        0b5054a54b00714f8180a9c0a940d1c0
        e100d10001014dd000a0f0703e803e30
        35000f282100001a000000ff0035394a
        4a34363532304c35420a000000fc0044
        454c4c205032343135510a20000000fd
        001d4c1e8c36000a2020202020200148
        02031df150101f200514041312110302
        161507060123091f0783010000565e00
        a0a0a02950302035000f282100001a02
        3a801871382d40582c25000f28210000
        1e011d007251d01e206e2855000f2821
        00001ea36600a0f0701f80302035000f
        282100001a0000000000000000000000
        000000000000000000000000000000eb
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
  3840x2160 (0x71) 533.250MHz +HSync -VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  3840 start 3902 end 3950 total 4000 skew    0 clock 133.31KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2163 end 2168 total 2222           clock  60.00Hz
  3840x2160 (0x72) 262.750MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  3840 start 3888 end 3920 total 4000 skew    0 clock  65.69KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2163 end 2168 total 2191           clock  29.98Hz
  2560x1440 (0x73) 241.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  2560 start 2608 end 2640 total 2720 skew    0 clock  88.79KHz
        v: height 1440 start 1443 end 1448 total 1481           clock  59.95Hz
  2048x1280 (0x74) 221.277MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  2048 start 2192 end 2416 total 2784 skew    0 clock  79.48KHz
        v: height 1280 start 1281 end 1284 total 1325           clock  59.99Hz
  1920x1200 (0x75) 193.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2056 end 2256 total 2592 skew    0 clock  74.56KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1203 end 1209 total 1245           clock  59.88Hz
  1920x1080 (0x76) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1082 end 1087 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x77) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x78) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock  56.25KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  50.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x79) 148.352MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz
  1920x1080i (0x7a) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.75KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
  1920x1080i (0x7b) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock  28.12KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock  50.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x7c) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2558 end 2602 total 2750 skew    0 clock  27.00KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  24.00Hz
  1920x1080i (0x7d) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.72KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz
  1920x1080 (0x7e) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2558 end 2602 total 2750 skew    0 clock  26.97KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  23.98Hz
  1600x1200 (0x4d) 162.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1664 end 1856 total 2160 skew    0 clock  75.00KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1201 end 1204 total 1250           clock  60.00Hz
  1600x900 (0x7f) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1624 end 1704 total 1800 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
        v: height  900 start  901 end  904 total 1000           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x1024 (0x80) 135.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1296 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  79.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  75.02Hz
  1280x1024 (0x52) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1152x864 (0x81) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1344 total 1600 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock  75.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x82) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  45.00KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x83) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1720 end 1760 total 1980 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  50.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x84) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  44.96KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  59.94Hz
  1024x768 (0x85) 78.750MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock  60.02KHz
        v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock  75.03Hz
  1024x768 (0x59) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x86) 49.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  816 end  896 total 1056 skew    0 clock  46.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  625           clock  75.00Hz
  800x600 (0x60) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  720x576 (0x87) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  732 end  796 total  864 skew    0 clock  31.25KHz
        v: height  576 start  581 end  586 total  625           clock  50.00Hz
  720x480 (0x88) 27.027MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  720x480 (0x89) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  640x480 (0x8a) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  720 total  840 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  500           clock  75.00Hz
  640x480 (0x8b) 25.200MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0x69) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  720x400 (0x8c) 28.320MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  738 end  846 total  900 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  400 start  412 end  414 total  449           clock  70.08Hz
  3840x2160_60.00 (0x145) 712.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 4160 end 4576 total 5312 skew    0 clock 134.18KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2163 end 2168 total 2237           clock  59.98Hz
```

Comment: Any ideas where I should start troubleshooting this?

Comment: Just to clarify,
It does not flicker when I use only the external monitor, or only the laptop screen. The external monitor only flickers when both are in use (dual screen setup).

Any ideas appreciated!